# TextBlock Visibility change WPF via Button hover

Tags: c#, wpf, hover, visibility

I am currenctly programming a little application, and i got stuck at the following point:

My Buttons have several Arguments in the code and i want to show the values in a seperate textblock.

Is there a possibility to change the visibility of the textblock when i hover over the button, so that the arguments are only visible when hovering over the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is, using the buttons `MouseEnter` event. somthing like the following would work fine:

```
button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBlock1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

And then to make it hidden, use the `MouseLeave` event:

```
button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBlock1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Solution, but how to i implement these Methods in the WPF-code? Because what i ment was something like         <Button Name="B3" Click="B3_Click_1" Margin="20,265,360,26"/> only with a hover-version

Comment: something like `<Button Name="Foo" Content="SomeContent" MouseEnter="button1_MouseEnter"/>`

Answer (score 3):

XAML solution:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="Foo" Visibility="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=Foo, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Bar" Visibility="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=Bar, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>

    <Button x:Name="Foo" Grid.Column="1" Content="Foo"/>
    <Button x:Name="Bar" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Bar"/>
</Grid>
```

where `converters` namespace is declared as:

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=PresentationFramework"
```